# CouchDB query using :group_level and :key

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I am using CouchDB 1.1.1 for my web app-- everything has worked great so far (saving/retrieving documents, saving/querying views, etc) but I am stuck on a querying a view for a particular key at a particular group level.

The map function in my view outputs keys with the following format: ["Thing 1" "Thing 2"]. I have a reduce function which works fine and outputs correct values for group level 1 (ie by "thing 1") and by group level 2 (ie by "thing 2").

Now-- when I query couchdb I CAN grab just one particular key when I set reduce = true (default), group_level=2 (or group=true, which are the same in this case since I only have 2 levels) and key = "desiredkeyhere." I can also query multiple keys with keys = ["key1" "key2"].

HOWEVER-- I really want to be able to grab a particular key for group_level=1, and I cannot get that to work. It seems to return nothing, or if use a post request, it returns everything. Never just the one key that I need.

Heres a link the the couchdb http view api (querying options) that I've been using: 
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

It contains the following sentence:
"Note: Multiple keys request to a reduce function only supports group=true and NO group_level (identical to group_level=exact). The resulting error is "Multi-key fetchs for reduce view must include group=true""

Im not sure if this means that I cannot do what I have described above (grab a particular key for a particular group_level). That would seem like a huge problem with couchdb, so Im assuming Im doing something wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/cloudant/chttpd/issues/20
As it says here, you cannot use any value other than group_level=exact with keys.

Answer (score 2):

I have hit this too. I am not sure if it is a bug, though.

Try using your `startkey` and `endkey` in the normal (2-item) format. You want a result for `["Thing 1", *]` (obviously pseudocode, the star represents anything). Reducing with `group_level=1` will boil all of that down to one row.

So, query basically everything in the Thing 1 "namespace," so to speak. Since the "smallest" value to collate is `null` and the "greatest" value is the object `{}`, those make good bookends for your range.

```
?group_level=1&startkey=["Thing 1",null]&endkey=["Thing 1",{}]
```

Does that give you the result you need?

Comment: This doesn't solve the multi-key problem, this is basically equivalent to a single key with group-level set to 1